# Ninject + Windows Forms Application

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject

I'am using Ninject + Windows Forms to build an application.

Mark Seemann (Injection in .NET book Author) says: Only one call of container.Get<> must construct all object gaph of your application.

I can't think a logical way to do that.

I was searching and wasting a lot of time for one code sample about how to do it, but i can't find.

On my application i have a Menu Form that call many other forms each one with your respective service (e.g ICustomerService).

Someone can help me with a code sample of a Windows Forms application with 3 or more forms each one calling another with Ninject?

Comment: without ServiceLocator.